# How to know what shapes number it is when generating powerpoint in Python

Tags: python, powerpoint

I'm trying to generate Powerpoint in python, but it's hard for me to figure out what is the shape number in ppt.

For example:

```
prs2.slides[1].shapes[3].table.cell(3,2).text_frame.text = 2000
prs2.slides[1].shapes[3].table.cell(3,2).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = 12
```

I use these code to find a table on the first slide, and make the text value of cell(3,2) as 2000, and then change the size to 12. But I have no idea of how can I know the table is shapes[3] of the first slide? What I'm doing now is try from shapes[0] to shapes[3], but I think there must be an easier way to identify the shape number.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 3):

via `win32com` each shape should have a [`type` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/shape-type-property-powerpoint) that corresponds to the [msoShapeType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/msoshapetype-enumeration-office). The `msoTable` type has a value of `19`.

```
for sh in prs2.slides[1].shapes:
    if sh.type == 19:  # msoTable = 19
        sh.table.cell(3,2).text_frame.text = 2000
        sh.table.cell(3,2).text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = 12
        break
```

If you're using python-pptx, then try the `graphicframe.has_table` property (note: you may need to test whether the shape *is* a graphicframe, first, or trap errors accordingly):

http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#graphicframe-objects

Comment: I tried your code, but there's an Error: AttributeError: 'GraphicFrame' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: When I use sh.type, it seems type is not an option after sh.

Comment: how are you handling powerpoint? Via win32com or some other package? It would be helpful to include that detail :)

Comment: I'm using pptx, not win32com, are you familiar with pptx?

Comment: I've used it once or twice. see revised answer.

Comment: Need some time to understand how it works. Thank you so much! : )